# Does Azcopy support piping?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, 7zip, azcopy

Here is my scenario

```
Invoke-sqlcmd -query "Select * from master.sys.table" -ServerInstance myserver -database -mydb | convert-csv | select -skip 2 | .\7z.exe a -si tgzip $gzipedfilename
```

Now I am taking that `$gzipedfilename` and uploading to blob storage using azcopy.
This is causing huge disk I/O  and queue when I am running above script in multiple threads. I am trying pipe Azcopy on the output of above script by doing

```
| .\7z.exe a -si tgzip -so | Azcopy -----
```

but I don't know if Azcopy supports piping and how. Can someone help? Or s there any other way to accomplish this by bypassing entire intermediate zipped file?

Answer (score 2):

Using azcopy_windows_amd64_10.2.1 I checked their help

```
.\azcopy.exe copy --help
```

and this shows that you can, at least now with block blobs, use piping

```
Upload a single file with a SAS using piping (block blobs only):
  - cat "/path/to/file.txt" | azcopy cp "https://..../[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]"
```

Comment: Add `--from-to PipeBlob`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, now it supports
example:

`cat testfile.txt | azcopy copy "https://[storage-account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[filename]?[sas_token]" --from-to PipeBlob`

Answer (score 1):

Currently AzCopy doesn't support pipeline. You can raise your feedback under http://aka.ms/azcopy if you want AzCopy support it in the future.

Comment: Does my reply solve your question? If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, which will help others find and resolve similar problem quickly.